# parallel execution of random forest in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am running random forest in R in parallel

```
library(doMC)
registerDoMC()
x <- matrix(runif(500), 100)
y <- gl(2, 50)
```

Parallel execution (took 73 sec)

```
rf <- foreach(ntree=rep(25000, 6), .combine=combine, .packages='randomForest') %dopar%
randomForest(x, y, ntree=ntree)
```

Sequential execution (took 82 sec)

```
rf <- foreach(ntree=rep(25000, 6), .combine=combine) %do%
randomForest(x, y, ntree=ntree)
```

In parallel execution, the tree generation is pretty quick like 3-7 sec, but the rest of the time is consumed in combining the results (combine option). So, its only worth to run parallel execution is the number of trees are really high. Is there any way I can tweak "combine" option to avoid any calculation at each node which I dont need and make it more faster

PS. Above is just an example of data. In real I have some 100 thousands features for some 100 observations.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Setting `.multicombine` to `TRUE` can make a significant difference:

```
rf <- foreach(ntree=rep(25000, 6), .combine=randomForest::combine,
              .multicombine=TRUE, .packages='randomForest') %dopar% {
    randomForest(x, y, ntree=ntree)
}
```

This causes `combine` to be called once rather than five times. On my desktop machine, this runs in 8 seconds rather than 19 seconds.

Comment: .combine=combine shoud better be .combine=randomForest::combine as there is dplyr::combine as well which leads to issues

Comment: Hey @Steve Weston, do you know how one might generalize this form to work within a sourced script? I've been stackoverflow stalking you on parallelization issues in R for a couple days, and its clear to me that if any one knows how to do this it would be you.

Comment: You'll want to use %dorng% from the doRNG package, instead of %dopar%, to ensure the different processors use different seeds.

Answer (score 12):

Are you aware that the [caret](http://cran.r-project.org/package=caret) package can do a lot of the hand-holding for parallel runs (as well as data prep, summaries, ...) for you?

Ultimately, of course, if there are some costly operations left in the random forest computation itself, there is little you can do as Andy spent quite a few years on improving it.  I would expect few to no low-hanging fruits to be around for the picking...

Answer (score 5):

H20 package can be used to solve your problem.

According to H20 [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/h2o/h2o.pdf) page H2O is "the open source
math engine for big data that computes parallel distributed
machine learning algorithms such as generalized linear models,
gradient boosting machines, random forests, and neural networks
(deep learning) within various cluster environments."

Random Forest implementation using H2O:

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/05/h2o-data-table-build-models-large-data-sets/

Answer (score 4):

I wonder if the [parallelRandomForest](https://bitbucket.org/mkuhn/parallelrandomforest) code would be helpful to you?

[According to the author](http://www.r-bloggers.com/introducing-parallelrandomforest-faster-leaner-parallelized/) it ran about 6 times faster on his data set with 16 times less memory consumption.

[SPRINT](http://www.ed.ac.uk/pathway-medicine/our-research/dpmgroups/ghazal-group/pathway-informatics/sprint) also has a parallel implementation [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/sprint/docs/prandomForest).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your CPU, you could probably get 5%-30% speed-up choosing number of jobs to match your number of registered cores matching the number of system logical cores. (sometimes it is more efficient to match number of system physical cores).
If you have a generic Intel dual-core laptop with Hyper Threading(4 logical cores), then DoMC probably registered a cluster of 4 cores. Thus 2 cores will idle when iteration 5 and 6 are computed plus the extra time starting/stopping two extra jobs. It would more efficient to make only 2-4 jobs of more trees.