# How to run randomForest in R on multiple cores in parallel?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, random-forest

I have a randomForest model that I want to calculate on multiple cores.
How can I tell the model to run in parallel?

This is not a duplicate of [parallel execution of random forest in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106010) as I don't need to run multiple models in parallel, I want one model to run in parallel.

Comment: @Florian no problem but please confirm for best of your knowledge if the combine will do this compared to run a full model. I mean if I will run foreach and use 5 "iterations" of 1000 trees and combine it's the same like doing one randomForest with ntree = 5000?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge; they are equivalent. A random forest is just growing independent trees with some randomness, so it does not matter if those trees were grown in separate forests or not. It would be a different case if we were growing a boosted forest for example, where the trees are no longer grown independently, but sequentially.

Comment: Using `ranger` or `rborist` will help. Faster and out of the box parallelization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the `doMC` package and its `registerDoMC` function. Works really well.