# Understanding the "Combine" Function

Tags: r

I am interested in running a Random Forest model on a very large dataset. I have been reading about "parallel computing" in an effort to make the code run faster. I came across this post over here ([parallel execution of random forest in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106010/parallel-execution-of-random-forest-in-r)) that had some suggestions:

```
library(randomForest)
library(doMC)

registerDoMC()
x <- matrix(runif(500), 100)
y <- gl(2, 50)

rf <- foreach(ntree=rep(25000, 6), .combine=randomForest::combine,
              .multicombine=TRUE, .packages='randomForest') %dopar% {
    randomForest(x, y, ntree=ntree)
}
```

I am trying to understand what is happening in the above code - my guess is that perhaps 6 Random Forest models (with each Random Forest Model having 25000 trees) are being fit to dataset and then combined into a single model?

I started looking into the "combine()" function in R (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf) - it seems that the "combine()" function is combining several Random Forest models into a single model (here, I think 3 Random Forest models are being combined into a single model):

```
data(iris)
rf1 <- randomForest(Species ~ ., iris, ntree=50, norm.votes=FALSE)
rf2 <- randomForest(Species ~ ., iris, ntree=50, norm.votes=FALSE)
rf3 <- randomForest(Species ~ ., iris, ntree=50, norm.votes=FALSE)
rf.all <- combine(rf1, rf2, rf3)
print(rf.all)
```

**My Question:** Can someone please confirm if I have understood this correctly? In the above code, are 6 Random Forest models being trained in parallel and then combined into a single model - is this correct?

**References:**

- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/519640/parallelizing-random-forest-learning-in-r-changes-the-class-of-the-rf-object
- https://rpubs.com/chidungkt/315749
- https://www.learnbymarketing.com/724/parallel-processing-r-basics/

Comment: You might easily check this yourself by taking a look at `body(randomForest::combine)`.

Comment: @ jay.sf : thank you for your reply! I have never heard of the "body()" function until now. A lot of code came out when I used "body(randomForest::combine)" - based on this code that came out, it was a bit difficult for me to understand what was happening!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would say yes. `foreach`'s `.combine=`arguments takes the function given for it to apply on the results the combination.